# Angular google-maps passing coordinates from $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Nicolas Laplante google-maps (http://nlaplante.github.io/angular-google-maps/) module. I have problem when passing coordinates for center property from asynchronous call:

This is my controller:

```
app.controller('baznaCtrl',function($scope,$routeParams,$http){
    $scope.idB=$routeParams;
    $scope.latitude=0;
    $scope.longitude=0;
    $http.get('https://my web service/json/'+$scope.idB.lokid).success(function(data){
        $scope.bs=data;
        $scope.latitude=$scope.bs.lattitude.replace(',','.');
        $scope.longitude=$scope.bs.longitude.replace(',','.');
    }); 

    angular.extend($scope,{
        center : {
            latitude: $scope.latitude,
            longitude:$scope.longitude
        },
        markers:[],
        zoom: 8
    });     
});
```

It seems that google-map does not changing it's center property when data comes from `$http` call. It is always 0,0 (because of initial values of `$scope.latitude` and `$scope.longitude`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use promises in angular js to make the ajax calls work perfectly.

Refer these examples:

[What is the best practice for making an AJAX call in Angular.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646034/what-is-the-best-practice-for-making-an-ajax-call-in-angular-js)

http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/

Comment: So you suggest that I have to put $http call in the factory and then use data from it as promise for google map center property?