# Factory that returns data after asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I have a service(factory) that uses another service to fetch data.Something like this:

```
factory('myFactory', function(anotherFactory) {

     var factoryObject = {};

     factoryObject.myMethod = () {

          var newObjectToReturn;

          // async call
          anotherFactory.get(id, function(data) {

              // do some processing
              newObjectToReturn = data; 
          });

          return newObjectToReturn;
     }
   return factoryObject;
});
```

Now, problem is of course, that because of asynchronous call, factoryObject.myMethod() always returns undefined, because  return newObjectToReturn is first executed, and I can't simply return data. Is there any way around this ?

Comment: Assuming your factory uses $http you should return the promise. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17646781/1522169

Answer (score -1, accepted):

return the response data in callback

factory('myFactory', function(anotherFactory) {

```
 var factoryObject = {};

 factoryObject.myMethod = () {

      var newObjectToReturn;

      // async call
      anotherFactory.get(id, function(data) {

          // do some processing
          newObjectToReturn = data; 
      },function(response){
           return newObjectToReturn;
      });
 }
```

return factoryObject;
});

Comment: That won't return it to anywhere useful.

Comment: U can return data from inside itself.

Comment: anotherFactory.get(id, function(data) {
 return data; 
});

Comment: You are passing that function as an argument. Something else will call that function. The value isn't being returned to anywhere useful.