# $HTTP service in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am new in `Angular.js`, and just learning it.

I am looking on `$http` service to send `AJAX` request.

I got three ways to send `AJAX` request form `Angular.js`.

These are here

1. `AJAX` calls via the `$http` service.
2. `JSONP` calls via the `$http` service.
3. `REST` type calls.

Actually I am getting confuse to these three process, that which is better for me to use.

Which will be more efficient and reliable for me to implement it in my project?

My main aim to make it high throughput.

Any suggestion will be helpful for me.

Comment: Go through this link : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best practice for making an AJAX call in Angular.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646034/what-is-the-best-practice-for-making-an-ajax-call-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner I would recommend you to go with the $http. Which is pretty straight forward and simple to use and serves most of the regular development tasks. The other two requires fair amount of understanding though they do the same job making ajax calls.