# Why return the promise and the data when using $http in an Angular service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-http

I frequently see tutorials and snippets online about Angular services to make $http calls that return both the $http promise and some data. If the promise is returned to the controller, what is the point of returning the data in the service? I don't even understand to where it is returned. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
 // Function of MyStuffService:
 function getStuff() {
    return $http.get('/api/stuff')
        .success(function(data) {
            // Why return data here? How could I even get this returned value?
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.error(data);
        });
}

// Controller:
function getStuff() {
    MyStuffService.getStuff()
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.stuff = data;
        })
}
```

Can't I just rewrite my service function as:

```
 // Function of MyStuffService:
 function getStuff() {
    return $http.get('/api/stuff')
        .error(function(data) {
            console.error(data);
        });
}
```

And let the controller get the data from the returned promise? I feel like I'm not understanding something here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What tutorials, and what snippets are you referring to?.. returning the data in the success callback is definitely strange.

Comment: For example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646034/what-is-the-best-practice-for-making-an-ajax-call-in-angular-js/17646781#17646781). There's a comment in there about stuff that only works in older versions of Angular, but I figured the first part was OK. So I should avoid that pattern? It would be fine to only do `function getStuff() {return $http.get('/api/stuff');}` in my service?

Comment: Yes.. i think its perfectly fine.

Comment: @Klodo: That answer doesn't use `success`, it uses `then`, from which you can indeed `return`. Admittedly, the identity function doesn't make much sense as a callback though.

Comment: @Bergi: I see, thank you. I guess should go read about the differences between success/error and then. I thought success was just syntactic sugar to have four parameters (`data, status, headers, config`) instead of just   `result`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The task is simple. Keep the controller thin and in your example you are using only one $http request.Whereas in a project we might be writing more $http requests. So we could have a single $http requests in a factory or service and call it everytime you needed just by passing variables. It reduces your coding time and keeps controller thin. I dont see any other advantages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data returned in the `.then` is available to the next chained `.then` handler, which is what you would ultimately use to get the data.

The `.success` just relays the original promise of `$http.get`. Returning data from `.success` doesn't do anything.

So, if you have:

```
 function getStuff() {
    return $http.get('/api/stuff')
        .success(function(data) {
            // do something with data. returning doesn't do anything
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.error(data);
        });
};
```

in the controller you would do:

```
getStuff().then(function(response){
  $scope.data = response.data; // this is the data available from `$http.get`
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that `success` works like `then`? I'm quite sure of the opposite

Comment: But success does not return a new promise, as demonstrated by the fact you can use a chained .error method after.

Comment: -1. In fact [`success` does not work like `then`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L814), and `return`ing from its callback is pointless.

Comment: @Bergi, ah, true... I missed that. Returning from `.success` is pointless - it just relays the original `$http` promise. Fixed.

Comment: I think there is a slight mistake in the code above. The `then` function should have a `result` parameter and not `data` since it is not equivalent to the `data` parameter of `success`.

Comment: @Klodo, yes - `data` is the response object in `.then`. The actual data would be `data.data`. I'll edit to make it clear, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you refer to does not return the data in success handler, it returns result.data in the then handler. That then, which generates a new chained promise, is then returned. This removes the http request data normally present in .then.

### Why bother?

The reason to work with .then instead of .success is for future proofing. .success is not part of promises, it's specific to $http. If you ever decide to later get the data from another async source (websockets, webworkers) your code will break when the promise you return no longer has a success handler.

By making it always return a .then, you make sure your services are sufficiently abstracted.

Comment: Actually, the real reason of using `then` over `success` is that it creates the chained promise for the return value of the callback, which `success` doesn't.

Comment: But there's no point in bothering with that if you're okay using `.success`, as the original promise given by `$http` has that method with the response data as it's only argument. The original question was asking why not bother just using `.success` in their controller.

Comment: Oh right, I referred to the `success` call in `MyStuffService.getStuff` not the one in the controller.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to explain why, in general, using .success is not a good choice. It's a little unfortunate those convenience methods exist, as it's confusing to people as they first try to learn promises, and `.success` and `.error` aren't part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would do that if you need to do some processing before sending data to controller.

But in this case, I agree as there is no processing of data, there is no need to need to resolve the promise in the service.

In this case, I would simply rewrite the service method as:-

```
function getStuff() {
   return $http.get('/api/stuff');
}
```

If I have to do some processing before returning data to the controller, I tend to use $q, as below.

```
function getStuff() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.get('/api/stuff')
        .then(function(data) {
            // some processing
            defer.resolve(processedData);
        }, function(error) {
            defer.reject(error);   
        });
        return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: [You really shouldn't do](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572). The return value of `$http.get` is a promise already, so just use `then`!

Comment: Sorry, my bad... I copy-pasted OP's code and changed it.... Agreed, I should have changed it to then...

Comment: No, I mean you should *use* `then` instead of creating a new deferred! Please read the post I've pointed to.

Comment: Ahh, got you now..I partly agree to that...But if my service is accessed from multiple places and the data needs conditioning before use, I would use this pattern or probably httpInterceptor to transform my response. But as I said in my reply, if no processing is required, I will just return the promise.

Comment: No, just don't use that pattern (ever)! If the data needs conditioning, you can and should use `then`.