# Correct syntax when calling an AngularJS javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JS function in an AngularJS JS file defined below and I'm calling it.

What would be the correct syntax when calling this function within the JS file itself because I need to do a hard refresh on a grid.

### FUNCTION

```
viewModel.getGridData = function (ajaxUrl, searchValues)
        {
            $http.post(ajaxUrl, { searchCriteria: searchValues })
            .success(function (data)
            {
                viewModel.gridOptions.data = data.kvs;
            });
        };
```

### CALL TO FUNCTION

```
viewModel.getGridData(ajaxUrl, searchValues);
```

Comment: is `viewModel` an object of your controller?

Comment: Yes, it's an object.

Comment: Bergi, the grid does not get refreshed. When I check the values of the variables in the call to the function, they are "undefined".

Comment: there isn't enough here to explain exactly what your issue is.  Your question says "what is the correct syntax....", but your *actual* question seems to be why you are getting an undefined value somewhere else, in some code or HTML you haven't even posted here.  Please consider fleshing out the question and the actual problem a bit more, and include a [mcve].

Comment: also, why are you using `$http.post` for what appears to be something that should be a GET operation?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider making "getGridData" a service function that returns a promise using Angular's internal $http service.  This pattern has the benefit of allowing you to reuse your ajax requests in other places within your application and [is considered by many to be a best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17646781/4206756).

```
myApp.factory('SearchService', function($http) {
    return {
      getGridData: function(url, valueObj) {
        return $http.post(url, valueObj);
      }
    }
});
```

The promise would resolve with the resolution of its internal ajax call,  so you would invoke the factory function in your controller (don't forget to inject it as a dependency!) with

```
SearchService.getGridData(url, valueObject).then(function(result) {
    //you will have access to the result of the Ajax call inside this callback function only.
    //Be sure to bind it for use in other places in your application!
    console.log(result);
})
```

Relevant reads:

[$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

[angular services docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)