# Calling a php file from angularJs

Tags: php, angularjs, wamp

Hi I'm trying to call a php from the angularjs control file.

Both PHP and Control file are in the same folders and inside `www` directory of `Wamp` and I'm calling php like this

```
`$scope.url='far_submit.php';`
$http.post($scope.url, {"name": $scope.fname, "email": $scope.email, "lname": $scope.lname}).
                 success(function(data, status) {...}
```

I'm getting an error in browser like `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/wamp/www/reg/far_submit.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Where I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: You need a webserver of some kind. You cannot make ajax requests on the `file://` protocol.

Comment: Then you need to hit your angularjs page via apache as well, not via `file://`.

Comment: You cannot run php outside a webserver unless in command line `$scope.url='http://localhost/reg/far_submit.php';` will give you result.

Comment: Now I'm geting this error now `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/reg/far_submit.php. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Sounds like you have a fresh new question to ask. While you're at it, google `CORS`

Comment: You need to access your application in the browser using http, not file (check the address bar)

Comment: OK in that case see my answer down below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$scope.url` should be,

```
$scope.url='http://localhost/reg/far_submit.php';
```

And your PHP file `far_submit.php` should start with

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: It's better to put the url without the ip address or domain name, Just the location is enough.

Answer (score -1):

The php file should be processed and served with a web server like [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org), [Nginx](http://nginx.org), [IIS](http://www.iis.net), etc.

And then your JavaScript should call the URL serving that PHP using an [Ajax method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646034/what-is-the-best-practice-for-making-an-ajax-call-in-angular-js)