# Referencing multiple API calls in one Service (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-service, angularjs-http

I am accessing an API via Angular $http requests to gather information for different football teams.

If I were to be only accessing one team, this would be fine - I would create a Service that made the call, then reference the Service function in my controller. However, I want to do this on numerous teams, without having to create a separate Service module for each one.

**Service**

```
app.factory('APIService', ['$http',
   function($http) {
      return $http.get('http://API/team/1204?Authorization=xxxxx')
      .success(function(data) {
        return data;
      })
        .error(function(err) {
        return err;
      });
   }
]);
```

**Inside my Controller...**

```
APIService.success(function(data) {
    $scope.apiData = data; 
});
```

As you can see in the Service, the team is specific, "1204", and will only pull in the data from that one team. I want to create a function that allows that four digit code to be interchangeable depending on the team, but I don't know how, or where to put it.

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I built a Generic Angular Service that is the only service you will need in your application.

https://github.com/cullimorer/AngularGenericAPIService

The service contains a number of different methods:

GET (array) - GetListData

GET - GetData

PUT - UpdateData

POST - AddData

DELETE - DeleteData

So, what's special about this? Well, what happens is you can call any endpoint passing in as many parameters as you like. This works a lot like the "string.Format" function in C# where it will take the value of objects specified and insert them into another string. The commonService contains a method called "stringFormat" which replicates this functionality for use by the generic API service.

Let's see how we do this in practice. If you wanted to call a restful API endpoint called "fooBars" passing in an "ID" of 1 to return a single "fooBar", we would do it like so:

```
return genericService.getData('fooBars/{0}', [1]);
```

This will call the API with the URL:

"http://localhost/API/fooBars/1"

The second parameter is an array, this way you can pass in as many parameters as you like into the string, let's say we have a number of "foos" and "bars" we might do something like this:

```
return genericService.getData('foos/{0}/bars/{1}', [1, 2]);
```

This will call the API with the URL:

"http://localhost/API/foos/1/bars/2"

And so forth. It's a pretty simple service but I use it in all AngularJS projects because it's so easy to implement and means you don't have to write a tonne of different queries in your Angular services or write long string concatenations.

Comment: You could have also able to add [link](https://github.com/cullimorer/AngularGenericAPIService) to answer as an comment

Comment: Do you know `ngResource`? Its sounds better in the situation of what OP has been asking

Comment: I've not come across it before, but it looks like it achieves the same result. Will definitely look to integrate it with future projects to try it out! Thanks.

Comment: I appreciated your efforts, that you made it +1, I'd just suggest you to add some more configuration to like, having its own transformRequest & transformResponse. +1 for all your efforts & star to your repo

Comment: Yea that's a great idea. If you'd like to propose some changes we could work on it together?